# Mount Kubernetes secret as a file with rw permission

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a file with in a POD from kubernetes sceret, but i am facing one issue like, i am not able to change permission of my deployed files.

I am getting below error,
**chmod: changing permissions of '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': Read-only file system**

I have already apply defaultmode & mode for the same but still it is not working.

```
volumes:
- name: gitsecret
  secret:
    secretName: git-keys
VolumeMounts:
- mountPath: "/root/.ssh"
  name: gitsecret
  readOnly: false
```

thank you

Answer (score 5):

As you stated, your version of Kubernetes is 1.10 and documentation for it is available [here](https://v1-10.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/)

You can have a look at the github link [@RyanDawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9705485/ryan-dawson) provided, there you will be able to find that this `RO` flag for `configMap` and `secrets` was intentional. It can be disabled using feature gate `ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes`.
You can follow this guide on how to [Disabling Features Using Feature Gates](https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/disabling_features.html).

As a workaround, you can try this approach:

```
containers:
  - name: apache
    image: apache:2.4
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["chown", "www-data:www-data", "/var/www/html/app/etc/env.php"]
```

You can find explanation inside Kubernetes docs [Attach Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/)

Answer (score 3):

There has been some back and forth over this but presumably you are on a k8s version where configmap and secret are read-only no matter how you set the flag - the issue is https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099 I think you'll need to follow the advice on there and create an emptyDir volume to copy the relevant files into.

Comment: Below is my kubernetes versionsClient Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.5", GitCommit:"32ac1c9073b132b8ba18aa830f46b77dcceb0723", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-21T11:46:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:25:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}